# Django - using a form from another app - issue creating a redirect

Tags: python, django, forms, redirect, submit

I have a contact app in my project.  To use the contact form from that app in the home page I created this in my views.py:

```
from django.views import generic
from contact.forms import ContactForm

class HomePage(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context=super(HomePage, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['form'] = ContactForm

        return context
```

When I submit the form on the home page it redirects to a blank page, instead of either the home page, or a thank you page.

Here is the definition in the views.py of the contact app:

```
def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name', '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email', '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')

            template = get_template('contact/contact_template.txt')
            context = dict({'contact_name': contact_name, 'contact_email': contact_email, 'form_content': form_content,})

            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New contact form submission",
                content,
                "Your website" +'',
                ['you@company.com'],
                headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email }
            )
            email.send()
            return render(request, 'contact/thank_you.html')

    return render(request, 'contact/contact.html', {
        'form': form_class,
    })
```

I noticed that filling the form and hitting submit does not output to the console like the contact app page, nor do I get the confirmation page.  I believe that means that I need to give the form a path to those files, or copy the files to the main templates directory, and tell the view where to find them.  Being new at Django - I'm totally lost.  I got as far as creating the creating the view, but now I'm struggling.  Help!

Comment: post your `home.html` and `urls.py`

Comment: There relevant part of home.html is:

<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
        <h2 class="text-center">The Form</h2>
        {% block form %}
          {% crispy form %}

        {% endblock form %}
      </div>

...and the two relevant urls are:
url(r'^$', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
url(r'^', include(contact.urls, namespace='contact')),

Like I said - the form renders correctly, but doesn't submit any data, and redirects to an empty page.

Comment: set the action to your form with `{% url 'contact' %}`,which the action is your post url.

Comment: ...not sure how to do that.  Do you mean in the home.html?

Comment: yes,set action for your ContactForm in home.html like `<form class="form"  action="{% url 'article_create' %}" `method="post">

Comment: Didn't work - got the error:  django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'contact' not found. 'contact' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: post your `contact/urls.py`

Comment: url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^subscribe/$', views.subscribe, name='subscribe'),

Comment: try  `action="/contact/"`

Comment: or action="{% url contact:contact %}"

Comment: Actually - after much ado, that worked.  It seems I had to manually define the form instead of using form tags.  Sorry about that - and thanks for the assist.

Comment: you are welcome,if you take the first answer which is my post will be better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action="contact/"` or  `action="{% url contact:contact %}"` for your form in home.html and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls) is url resovle doc.

you can simplify your code by class based view like [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) or [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview)

```
from django.views.generic import FormView, CreateView
```

Comment: Thanks - but I want to solve this one as part of the learning process.  I get the class based forms are simpler, and appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to another page on successful submission of form then you can use this is your view part,

```
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('url-name')
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry - didn't work.  I'm missing something here - it's not posting anything to the console so it seems some action is missing.

Comment: Change your contact method to Class based view and inside the contact class, apply `get_success_url` method

Comment: Thanks - but I want to solve this one as part of the learning process. I get the class based forms are simpler, and appreciate your reply.